How to search primers with primerTree within a specific taxa?
I'm trying to develop an eDNA metabarcoding assay and I'm searching using the r package primerTree to search universal fish primer pairs. When I search I don't want to search for all organisms that have a sequence that works. I want to search only within a specific genus. Does anyone know how to do this?
Tele01 <- search_primer_pair(forward = 'ACACCGCCCGTCACTCT', reverse = 'CTTCCGGTACACTTACCATG', name = 'Tele01', num_aligns = 5000)
